# Подключение интернет в OpenSuse

Tags: opensuse

Установил OpenSuse, настроил подключение к интернет через DSL, однако в системном трее нет значка, благодаря которому можно включить и отключить соединение. Как включить и отключить соединение с интернет?

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что поможет, так как не знаком с OpenSuse, но все же поробуйте так:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager start
```

(посмотрите в трей, значек должен появиться)